# _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL (xCode)

Tags: xcode, kivy, python-imaging-library, kivymd

Ive been trying to upload my first Kivy/KivyMD application using xCode. My app's name is MathDojo. Upon running my app, my program builds successfully but the app crashes when opened. Here is the error I see:

```
File "/Users/gavinthon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9B293397-1AC6-4A1D-B8E8-9C0E137CB90D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BFE0E5E9-A62E-4B04-8ABF-4525056C921C/mathdojo.app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/elevation.py", line 364, in <module>
     from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
   File "/Users/gavinthon/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9B293397-1AC6-4A1D-B8E8-9C0E137CB90D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BFE0E5E9-A62E-4B04-8ABF-4525056C921C/mathdojo.app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 92, in <module>
     raise ImportError(
 ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
 Core version: 8.2.0
 Pillow version: 9.0.0
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow in the environment I'm working on

```
pip3 uninstall pillow
pip3 install pillow
```

Could you please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: what is your pillow version?